# while-loop problem for acess a list element

Tags: python, arrays, list, recursion, while-loop

- I want to append each element of `[1,2]` to `[[1], [2], [3]]` and as
  a consequence, the final array that I want is `[[1,1], [1,2], [2,1], [2,2], [3,1], [3,2]]`

  But my code has a mistake I couldn't recognize it yet, and the result of the python code below is `[[1, 1, 2], [1, 1, 2], [2, 1, 2], [2, 1, 2], [3, 1, 2], [3, 1, 2]]`

The python code:

```
tor=[]
arr=[1,2]
arz=[[1], [2], [3]]

each=0
while each<len(arz):
       
    eleman=arz[each]
    index=0
    while index < len(arr):
        k=arr[index]
        eleman=arz[each]
        eleman.append(k)
        tor.append(eleman)
        index = index+1
    
    each=each+1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it would be `eleman=arz[each].copy()` as lists are mutable so every time you change an element in the original list it will get reflected in the resultant array

Comment: what is the function of .copy() ? why it is necessary ?

Comment: copy basically creates a shallow copy of the variable

Comment: I have noticed yet that .copy() is needed for copy of a list element which is in a list (list of list). Is that right ?

Comment: yes copy is needed because you are appending items to the same list in loop which will basically use the same reference in the loop, resulting in the result that you are getting

Comment: in fact if you will print your arz list it has also changed because of using same reference, copy will prevent this from happening

Comment: It is OK. But why we do not need it for arr list ? It is also in while loop list, but it works without .copy()

Comment: because in arr list the fundamental value you get is integer after accessing it, also if you change k nothing will get affected now because integers are immutable, also you are not appending or changing anything in the arr list, whereas your `eleman` variable contains a list which is mutable

Comment: I am fully clarified now !

Answer (score 0):

In this example it would be more useful to use a `for loop`. You can use it to loop through both lists, and append in pairs.

```
arr = [1, 2]
arz = [[1], [2], [3]]
tor = []

for i in arz:
    for j in (arr):
        tor.append([i[0], j])

print(tor)
```

Comment: why " i[0] " is necessary ? why not " i " ? Thank you for your answer

Comment: if you look at `arz`: notice that the first item is not `1`, but `[1]`. So you have to grab the first item of it.

Comment: It is OK. It is just a "a list of a list".

Answer (score 0):

You can use Python list `comprehension` to achieve this in one line:

```
a1 = [1, 2]
a2 = [[1], [2], [3]]

result =  [[i[0], j] for i in a2 for j in a1]

print(result)
```

- For this kind of operations don't use `While` loop but the `for` loop. It is much cleaner and simpler to use with iterables.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I ask this question intentionally to understand where problem is. May you explain it ?